# Streamchat.io: Accessing a user's teams

Tags: swift, getstream-io

I'm trying out [Stream's chat API](https://getstream.io/chat/). It is possible to enable [multi-tenancy](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/multi_tenant_chat/?language=swift), so that users can only search for other contacts that are in the same teams as themselves. I want to query for a user's contacts. If you do that you have to specify a team filter like so:

```
Client.shared.queryUsers(filter: .contains("teams", "Chicago Bulls"))
```

Of course I would like to not hardcode the team name for other users that aren't members of the Chicago Bulls. How do I do that? There's no `teams` properties on `User` in the [Swift SDK](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift) as far as I can see, so you can't just do `Client.shared.user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support is added at https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift/pull/295
Grab the new version.